# Concurrent writes to mkfifo seem to get lost

Tags: linux, bash, unix, pipe, named-pipes

I am writing a script that will setup an environment of machines.  I have the ability to put a startup script on the machines and so I am trying to use a named pipe `mkfifo` in unix on my "workstation" machine that will listen for writes from these new machines when they come online.

The problem is, I have no control over when these machines may come online.  In total there are over 20 machines that are being started simultaneously and I have tried to simulate the effects of a named pipe being written to multiple times before it has a chance to read and have had startling results....

I wrote two small test scripts:

mkfifogen.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo h
testing=""
sleep 10
for((i=0;i<5;i++));do
    echo $I
    while read line;do
       testing+="$line"
    done < h
done

echo "$testing"
rm -f h
```

and

mkfifowrite.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=0;i<5;i++));do
    echo "this is a test $i" > h
done
```

When I run the mkfifogen.sh followed by the mkfifowrite.sh the output is as follows

```
0
1
2
```

Then the mkfifowrite.sh script exits and the mkfifogen.sh script hangs

I then have to run the mkfifowrite.sh script 3 more times, and each time it will cause the output on the mkfifogen.sh script to increment one more time.  The last run will cause the value of testing to be output 4 times, so my output after 4 runs of the mkfifowrite.sh script and once of the mkfifogen.sh script looks like this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
this is a test 0this is a test 1this is a test 2this is a test 3this is a test 4
this is a test 0this is a test 1this is a test 2this is a test 3this is a test 4
this is a test 0this is a test 1this is a test 2this is a test 3this is a test 4
this is a test 0this is a test 1this is a test 2this is a test 3this is a test 4
```

What I am expecting to see after running mkfifogen.sh and mkfifowrite.sh once each is simply this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
this is a test 0this is a test 1this is a test 2this is a test 3this is a test 4
```

I have looked around online quite a bit and there are some cryptic answers to this, but I can't seem to make much sense out of them. I feel like this link might hold my answer, but I'm not sure https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68146/what-are-guarantees-for-concurrent-writes-into-a-named-pipe

TL;DR:

How do I ensure that all writes to a named pipe, regardless of quick in succession they are executed, are handled independently by the read?

Comment: Down voter, do you have a reason? If so, please comment on how I can improve my question...

Comment: This is a little tricky. First, are you intentionally opening and closing the pipe in `mkfifowrite.sh` at each iteration, or do you want a single run of `mkfifowrite.sh` to correspond to a single iteration of the `for` loop in `mkfifogen.sh`? Second, I'm getting different results depending on which version of `bash` I used, and possibly whether I run this under macOS or Linux. Which version of `bash` are you using?

Comment: Yes, each iteration of the for loop would emulate a different write to the pipe, like a machine coming online and relaying its status.  I am running this on RHEL. @chepner

Comment: Essentially, I want to understand what happens when writes stack up on the pipe before the read has an attempt to read the first one.

Comment: Note that you aren't testing concurrent writes; you have a single reader and a single writer, and that writer is just making a series of sequential writes. The real problems will happen if you try to run `mkfifowrite.sh` multiple times in *parallel*.

Comment: Before `read` gets called, writes will simply block. You will want to read up on the [readers-writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers–writers_problem), though.

Comment: On CentOS 7 with `bash` 4.2, I get your expected output. (With and without the `sleep` call; because `read` and writes will both block, it's not really necessary.)

Comment: Ok. I’ll take a look at the link.  Yea, unfortunately I can’t change the distro.

Comment: I put the sleep there to see what would happen if a bunch of writes piled up.   I’m trying to see worse case scenario, how my real script will behave with multiple machines sshing writes to the pipe potentially at the same time

Answer (score 0):

The reader reads until EOF, then repeats, until 5 EOFs have been received.

The writer opens and closes the pipe 5 times. Every time the writer closes the pipe, a potential EOF condition exists. It doesn't become an actual EOF until the reader attempts to read it (after reading everything that was written before).

During this potential EOF phase, there's a race. The writer is incrementing `i` and preparing to open the pipe for writing again, while the reader is completing the `read` command and processing the result, after which it will try to read again.

If the writer performs an open for writing before the reader attempts the read, the potential EOF condition disappears. If the reader attempts the read while the writer is no longer connected to the pipe, the EOF happens.

As you can see, when there are multiple writers to a pipe (whether sequential or parallel), EOFs are a pain. You can't expect them to reliably show up between messages from different writers. My way out of this would be to design the protocol so that the reader doesn't need EOFs to recognize the end of a message, and then have the reader open the pipe in read+write mode so there will *always* be at least one existing writer, and EOF will never occur.

Keeping the messages under `PIPE_BUF` size so they don't get split up is a separate issue, which you also have to pay attention to.

Comment: The multiple writers are sequential. One doesn't begin until the previous one completes. There's no race condition there.

Comment: @chepner I didn't say there was a race between 2 writers. I described (in great detail!) the race between the writer and the reader.